# Update data in (really) real-time with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

hi

I want to build a control panel for a web art application that needs to run in fullscreen, so all this panel, that controls stuff like colors and speed values, have to be located at a different window.

My idea is to have a database storing all these values and when I make a change in the control panel window the corresponding variable in the application window gets updated too. So, it's basically a real-time update that I could do with AJAX setting a interval to keep checking for changes **BUT** my problem is: I can't wait 30 seconds or so for the update to happen and I guess a every-1-second AJAX request would be impossible.

Final question: is there a way to create a sort of a listener to changes in the database and fire the update event in the main application only immediately after I change some value in the control panel? Does Angular or another framework have this capability?

(Sorry for the long explanation, but I hope my question is clearer by offering the context [: )

Comment: Sounds like you want web-sockets - or with Angular, FireBase may be worth looking into

Comment: Firebase seems perfect! Thank you, i'm going to take a look (:

Comment: Another alternative is the MEAN stack. http://mean.io/#!/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web socket powered application would have this benefit. This carries a bit more complexity on the back end, but has the benefit of making your application as close to real-time as can be reasonably expected.

The Mozilla Development Network has some good [documentation on websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets).

On the front end, the WebSocket object should work for you on most modern browsers.

I'm not sure what your back end is written in, but [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) for Node.js and [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) for Python will make your applications web-socket capable

Answer (score 0):

If one window is opening the other windows via *JavaScript*, you can keep the reference to the opened window and use [`otherWindow.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to pass *messages* across

"Parent" window looks like

```
// set up to receive messages
window.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    if (e.origin !== 'http://my.url')
        return; // ignore unknown source
    console.log(e.message);
});

// set up to send messages
var otherWindow = window.open('/foo', '_blank');
otherWindow.postMessage('hello world', 'http://my.url');
```

"Child" windows look similar

```
// same setup to recieve
// ...

// set up to send
var otherWindow = window.opener;
// ... same as before
```

Answer (score 0):

For the realtime I would recommend using a library like [socket.io](http://socket.io/) or using a database like [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/).

For the fullscreen I would recommend using a library like [angular-screenfull](https://github.com/hrajchert/angular-screenfull)

Answer (score 0):

i use https://pushjs.io/, had exactly the same problem and this is a really simple solution for your problem. It is capable of sending and listening to events without any database interference.